# vba treat time as string

Tags: vba, excel

I am storing some values in my excel using vba and them comparing with other results. The results can be whatever: name, surname, address, time...

The problem that I have is that when I store a string that has a date format it takes it as time automatically. For example if I enter 8:15 it automatically convert it to 08:15 and then when I am comparing it with other value that is the same (8:15) it returns me false because it is not 08:15.

So basically the question is... how can I introduce a value like 8:15 without being converted to 08:15?

Comment: how are you comparing them? and what are both datatypes? Please give us more details how the values are assigned(code?) how you're comparing etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods:

1. Put an apostraphe at the front of the value to tell Excel it's a string. Example: The value `'8:15` will be interpreted as a string of value "8:15".
2. Use a formula to store the value as a string. Example: `="8:15"` is also interpreted as a string of value "8:15".

Comment: Same thing applies from my comment below the other answer. The OP didn't bother providing more details so your answer does not really answer the question.

Comment: @mehow, the only time excel would auto correct strings is if they were stored in cells..... if you put "8:15" in a vba string, it would not auto correct to "08:15", thus this works perfect. mine would work too, but this is better

Comment: @user1759942 I have explained under your answer why I disagree and any professional would probably agree with me. I am not in anyway trying to discourage you(*or anyone else*) from answering but Stack Overflow used to be so great because you used to get answers from [**Einsteins not Morts**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/11/mort-elvis-einstein-and-you.html)

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming this is when you're entering the values in Cells. the format of the cells is probably general, thus it formats things like numbers or dates different. Change it to text.

select all (or specific columns) right click - format cells - number tab - text option. it says there "text format cells are treated as text even when a number is in the cell. the cell is displayed exactly as entered"

### edit

another option, in VBA use `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.value` when comparing. `.value` is the actual value of the cell (like a formula result) where as `.formulaR1C1` will give you the actual entered text. so .formulaR1C1 might get you the actual entered 8:15 instead of the corrected value: 08:15.

Comment: Well, how about `Dim t1$: t1 = "08:15"`, `Dim t2$: t2 = "8:15"` and then `Debug.print CDate(t1) = CDate(t2)` which returns `True`. This is how you would properly solve this using VBA and not rely on the formatting of cells which can be easily manipulated. Also, (*although not recommended*) it's to remove leading `0`. Also, bear in mind that Excel stores dates as decimals therefore if you compare the `.Values` then those Values should be the same even though they may have been displayed differently on spreadsheet.